# sql group by with count to know the status

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

Hi all i have two tables like this one is `subscripiton` having columns below like this ..

```
Id  SubscriptionKey  
 1   subkey1
 2   subkey2
 3   subKey3
```

another table is **guardkey**   having columns like below

```
 id     key    SubscriptionKey   IsConverted
  1     key1     subkey1           True
  2     key2     subkey1           true
  3     key3     subkey2           true
  4     Key4     subkey2           false
  5     key5     subkey2           true
  6     key6     subKey1           false
  7     key7     subkey3           true
  8     key8     subkey3           true
```

how can we find out whether the all keys related to particular subkey is converted or not ..

I am binding this data to gridview and i need to disable the particular row if all keys for that particular subkey is converted

Could any one please help on this how to check whether all keys are converted for particular key..

Many thanks in advance..

I am using sql server..

**Expected output** is like this

```
 subscriptionkey 
      subkey1
      subkey2
```

Comment: Whats is your expected output?

Comment: hi ... i modified  question to get expected output like above mentioned..

Comment: @AbdulRasheed i modified my question to reflect expected output ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT SubscriptionKey
FROM guardkey
GROUP BY SubscriptionKey
HAVING COUNT(*) <> COUNT(CASE WHEN IsConverted = 'True' THEN 1 END)
```

`HAVING` clause use `COUNT` function twice:

- The first time to count all records of the group (`COUNT(*)`)
- The second time to *conditionally* count the 'converted' records of the group.

If these two counts are different then the subkey is not converted and its value is returned by the query.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d17b6/1)

**Edit:** To get the rest of the fields from `subscription` table you can use the above query as a derived table:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM subscription AS s
JOIN (
    SELECT SubscriptionKey
    FROM guardkey
    GROUP BY SubscriptionKey
    HAVING COUNT(*) <> COUNT(CASE WHEN IsConverted = 'True' THEN 1 END)
) AS t ON s.SubscriptionKey = t.SubscriptionKey
```

Comment: Thanks for the query.. but i need to select other column  info from subscripiton  table ... how can i get that ..

Answer (score 1):

This will be the simple approach for archiving the above

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    SubscriptionKey VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @T2 TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    [key] VARCHAR(50),
    SubscriptionKey VARCHAR(50),
    IsConverted BIT
)

INSERT INTO @t1
VALUES(1,'SubKey1'),
(2,'SubKey2'),
(3,'SubKey3')

INSERT INTO @T2
VALUES
(1,'key1','subkey1',1),
(2,'key2','subkey1',1),
(3,'key3','subkey2',1),
(4,'Key4','subkey2',0),
(5,'key5','subkey2',1),
(6,'key6','subKey1',0)

SELECT
    *
    FROM @T1 t1
        WHERE EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 FROM @T2 T2 WHERE T2.SubscriptionKey = t1.SubscriptionKey AND IsConverted = 1
        )
        AND NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 FROM @T2 T2 WHERE T2.SubscriptionKey = t1.SubscriptionKey AND IsConverted = 0
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this-

--NOT CONVERTED SubscriptionKeys

```
SELECT [id], [key], [SubscriptionKey], [IsConverted]
FROM 
(
    SELECT * , COUNT(CASE WHEN IsConverted = 'True' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY SubscriptionKey) a
             , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SubscriptionKey) b     
    FROM guardkey
)x WHERE a = b

id          key  SubscriptionKey IsConverted
----------- ---- --------------- -----------
7           key7 subkey3         true
8           key8 subkey3         true
(2 rows affected)
```

--CONVERTED SubscriptionKeys

```
SELECT [id], [key], [SubscriptionKey], [IsConverted]
FROM 
(
    SELECT * , COUNT(CASE WHEN IsConverted = 'True' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY SubscriptionKey) a
             , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SubscriptionKey) b     
    FROM guardkey
)x WHERE a < b

id          key  SubscriptionKey IsConverted
----------- ---- --------------- -----------
1           key1 subkey1         True
2           key2 subkey1         true
6           key6 subKey1         false
3           key3 subkey2         true
4           Key4 subkey2         false
5           key5 subkey2         true


(6 rows affected)
```